# Ajax call shows plain html

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have CKEditor & i save that as a Html in my database.Then i'm going to get that saved html stream & show it inside div But it shows the html codes.

My webmethod return below line

```
<p> <strong>Test Heading </strong></p> <p> <img alt="" src="http://s7.postimg.org/511xwse93/mazda_familia_photo_large.jpg" style="width: 150px; height: 112px;" /></p> <p> test description goes here</p>
```

Div

```
<div id="usrnewsdesc"></div>
```

My Ajax Call

```
     function LoadNewsToUsers() {
       debugger;

       var newurl = '<%= ResolveUrl("/WebMethods.aspx/GetIndividualUserNews") %>';

        $.ajax({
            url: newurl,
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({ ToUser: "<%=GetUserID()%>" }),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (Result) {
                $.each(Result.d, function (key, value) {

                    var html ="<body>"+value.News+"</body>";
                    $("#usrnewsdesc").append(html);

                });

            },


            error: function (e, x) {
                alert(x.ResponseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

My div looks like this
[image: mydiv]

My WebMethod

```
 [WebMethod, ScriptMethod]
public static List<UserNews> GetIndividualUserNews(Guid ToUser)
{
    List<UserNews> UserNewsDetails = new List<UserNews>();
    try
    {
        SqlCommand comGetAllFiles = new SqlCommand("SP_GetNewsToUser", conDB);
        comGetAllFiles.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        if (conDB.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            conDB.Open();
        comGetAllFiles.Parameters.Add("@ToUser", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
        comGetAllFiles.Parameters["@ToUser"].Value = ToUser;

        SqlDataReader rdr = comGetAllFiles.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(rdr);
        foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
        {
            UserNewsDetails.Add(new UserNews
            {
                Id = (int)r["Id"],
                News = r["News"].ToString(),
                DateTime =(DateTime) r["DateTime"],
                ToUser = (Guid)r["ToUser"]

            });
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        conDB.Close();
    }
    return UserNewsDetails;
}
```

Console.log is below

```
  &lt;p&gt;
    &lt;strong&gt;Test Heading &lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;
    &lt;img alt=&quot;&quot; src=&quot;http://s7.postimg.org/511xwse93/mazda_familia_photo_large.jpg&quot; style=&quot;width: 150px; height: 112px;&quot; /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;
    test description goes here&lt;/p&gt;
```

Comment: whats the problem again?

Comment: What exactly does the response string look like?

Comment: Inside the div it shows the webmethod return html coding as it is

Comment: @themerlinproject i use $("#usrnewsdesc").html(html); but not success

Comment: @themerlinproject [not true](http://jsbin.com/ruxame/1/edit)

Comment: I learn something new everyday!

Comment: Are you sure that your HTML is well formed?

Comment: @GSiry CKEditor saved html looks like this <p> <strong>Test Heading </strong></p> <p> <img alt="" src="http://s7.postimg.org/511xwse93/mazda_familia_photo_large.jpg" style="width: 150px; height: 112px;" /></p> <p> test description goes here</p>

Comment: Take the HTML that is in your db. Paste it in notepad. Save as HTML and open in your browser .. See what shows up

Comment: Hey.. It looks like you are appending a body tag to a div.. Is that legit ?

Comment: Appending the `<body>` tag is invalid but I don't *think* it'd cause the problem. @TechGuy you definitely should not be doing that in any case. You need to look at the actual JSON in the response; your browser can show you that in the developer tools.

Comment: @Pointy I am wondering if some browsers might not render the HTML correctly because of invalid HTML..

Comment: @Pointy I checked it with Firebug & alertResult.d & it shows [Object,Object]

Comment: @GSiry I just save exact return html stream in .html file..It's working fine

Comment: You are inserting `body` inside a `div`? not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decode your html content before you can use it as html.

```
success: function (Result) {
    $.each(Result.d, function (key, value) {

        var html = $("<div/>")        // temp container
                    .html(value.News) // "render" encoded content to text
                    .text();          // retrieve text (actual html string now)

        // body tags are a bad idea here but whatever.
        html = "<body>" + html + "</body>"; 

        $("#usrnewsdesc").append(html);

    });

},
```

With credit to this post for the decoding instruction: [How to decode HTML entities using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147359/how-to-decode-html-entities-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the correct output. No wrong is there. It is HTML Encoded, you have to decode it. You can use NewtonSoft json serializer to Decode it. Convert it and then return it from server side. Better if you could replace on the javascript side before applying it with append, because if the server return  sometimes, your client js will be broken Other than this all codes are okay

Try replacing quotes with js -

```
var s = value.News.replace('&lt;','<').replace('&gt;','>').replace('&squote','\'').replace('&quote','"');
$("#usrnewsdesc").html(s);
```

may be this will help or use `NewtonSoft` JSON serializer-

Comment: Can you show the server side action code that is returning the result?

Comment: when i use your edited code it shows the error in firebug console is TypeError: value.Niews is undefined

Comment: Now it shows the plain html code inside div like this <strong>Test Heading </strong></p> <p> <img alt="" src="http://s7.postimg.org/511xwse93/mazda_familia_photo_large.jpg" style="width: 150px; height: 112px;" /></p> <p> test description goes here</p>

Comment: Edited again... if this does not fix, may be you need to look into encoding and decoding.

Comment: No.it also same plain html looks like