# make angularjs escape ampersand in json

Tags: javascript, angularjs

http://plnkr.co/edit/vFOd0aMnmhMB047bUgoR?p=preview

angularjs turn single quote into this `o&#39;s`. One of the result you can see became

```
Kid&#39;s reaction meeting gay couple 4 the 1st time
```

I console.log the callback there is nothing like `&#39;s`, so I suspect that is cause by angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a problem with Angular.

Open the URL you're loading (list.php) - the HTML entities are already present in the JSON you're retrieving.

I'd say it's not a standard practice (you would normally place plain text the JSON, not any encoded representation). On how to untangle that, see the [tips in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12945405/399317).

Comment: in list.php I do echo json_encode($arr), and I don't see any strange character in data.