# Replacing special character code by respective special character automatically

Tags: jquery

```
$('#emailsubmit').click(function(){
    var data = CKEDITOR.instances.message.getData();
    data=data.replace(/\"/g,'&quot;');
    data=data.replace(/&nbsp;/g,' ');
    data=data.replace(/&copy;/g,'&#169;');
    $('#message_text').val(data);
});
```

This is the jquery function for replacing the special character code by special character.And I set it manually and I want set automatically ,how this could be done ?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do looks a lot like **html decoding**. A much better way of accomplishing the same thing - with support for *any* HTML entities - is the approach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147359/how-to-decode-html-entities-using-jquery):

```
// Get the encoded string from the editor
var data = CKEDITOR.instances.message.getData();

// Decode it - this is where the magic happens =)
var decoded = $("<div/>").html(data).text();

// Set the textbox value
$('#message_text').val(decoded);
```

As Vaibs_Cool suggested in his answer, you can wrap this in a function, and then set that function as an event handler for whatever event you want to trigger on.

Answer (score 0):

```
function replace_word(){  
    var data = CKEDITOR.instances.message.getData();
    data=data.replace(/\"/g,'&quot;');
    data=data.replace(/&nbsp;/g,' ');
    data=data.replace(/&copy;/g,'&#169;');
    $('#message_text').val(data);
}
```

And use this function on keypress on any input you are using.

Comment: is there is any function to replace special character code by special character like " can be replaced by &quot; etc..