# Special Character in PHP and JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, special-characters

We have list of names with special characters such as

Jay O'Coney

Bryăn Parker

We would like it to be saved in the database and also fetch using AJAX.

Tried:

```
//php
Return Response::JSON(array('name' => htmlentities($name, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8")));

//in jquery
$('#name').html(html_entity_decode('Name: ' + name,ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8"));
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: does your database have the utf8 encoding?

Comment: yes we have utf8 encoding

Answer (score -1):

try with,

```
utf8_encode($string);
```

Comment: refer this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147359/how-to-decode-html-entities-using-jquery