# Exploiting jquery html encoding XSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, xss

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode) users warned that this method of encoding html is unsafe

```
    return $('<div/>').html(encodedText).text();
```

> "don't use jQuery.html().text() to decode html entities as it's unsafe
>   because user input should never have access to the DOM
>   "
>
> "I suggest using a safer, more optimized function"

The purpose of this method is to take encoded input i.e `Fish &amp; chips` and produce unencoded output i.e `Fish & Chips`

So as I understand it, they claim that for some value of `encodedText`, that javascript can be executed. I tried to reproduce this setting `encodedText` to `<script>alert(1)</script>` and a few other simple attacks and was unable to find any signs of XSS vulnerability.

My question is: is there any demonstrable xss vulnerability in any browser when using `$('<div/>').html(encodedText).text()`

Comment: Especially note this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1395954/18771

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are plenty of ways of doing it, this is one way with onerror with an image tag.

```js
var x = $("<div/>").html('<img src="X" onerror="alert(\'hi\');" />').text();
console.log(x);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('<div/>').html('<img onerror="alert(0)" src=invalid>').text()
```