# Exploiting jQuery HTML decoding using textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, xss

Following up on [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31282274/exploiting-jquery-html-encoding-xss)...

This code can be exploited if an attacker has access to `encodedText`:

```
return $('<div/>').html(encodedText).text();
```

e.g. `$("<div/>").html('<img src="X" onerror="alert(\'hi\');" />').text()` displays an alert.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147359/how-to-decode-html-entities-using-jquery/1395954#1395954) recommends using a `textarea` instead to avoid XSS vulnerability:

```
return $('<textarea/>').html(encodedText).text();
```

This was able to handle the previous exploit safely.

However, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9609450/2377920) indicates that there are still XSS vulnerabilities when using `textarea`:

> I suggest using a safer, more optimized function

> don't use jQuery.html().text() to decode html entities as it's unsafe because user input should never have access to the DOM

My question is: Is there a way in any browser to exploit `$('<textarea/>').html(encodedText);` to run XSS assuming attacker has access to `encodedText`?

Comment: `$('<textarea/>').html('<script>alert()</script>').text();` would still run the script. I don't see any benefit from using `<textarea>`.

Comment: oh crap you're absolutely right, `textarea` handles the exploit I posted but not your even simpler one!

Comment: That's because the browser (or at least Chrome) wouldn't fire the `onerror` event when the `<img>` element is part of a `<textarea>`. But if the attacker has access to `encodedText` then simple script injection would run nonetheless. You need to ask yourself why is `encodedText` controlled by the end-user? Is it something that stored in a database (sanitize it upon saving then), is it injected through some request parameter (don't do it, or at least try to manipulate it before parsing /  attaching it to the DOM in any way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a comment by @haim770 gave me:

```
$('<textarea/>').html('<script>alert()</script>').text();
```

It seems like `$('<textarea/>').html()` doesn't help at all with safely parsing user input.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't risk is to be honest, it would be a lot safer if you handled anything that needed to be encrypted or unencrypted server-side.

Comment: the purpose of this method is to convert a string like `me &amp; you` to `me & you`. so I could do that server side but I then write it to the page. writing unencoded html special characters to the page would be another XSS attack. e.g the user could write `<script>alert('lol')</script>`. so if I want to write the data to the page and then display it, I'll have to encode it on the server, then unencode it on the client.