# Outputting HTML entities in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, escaping, html-entities

I'm struggling with the simple syntax of outputting HTML entities.

For the sake of simplicity:

```
document.write("&eacute;");
```

I want to output `&eacute;` as `é`.

I've tried it with quotation marks, apostrophes, and no marks.

The only way I've managed to get it to work is `/&eacute;/` but that outputs `/é/`.

Can somebody inform me of the correct way of doing this (*and if possible explain why the slashes are doing their thing*)?

I'm not familiar with jQuery so I'd appreciate if you keep answers in core JavaScript.

https://jsfiddle.net/e2ezz2h1/

Comment: Don't use `document.write`, use `innerHTML` (if you want to use entities) or `textContent` (if you want to keep the ampersands)

Comment: I'm actually trying to write it into a textbox's `value` rather than its `innerHTML`. https://jsfiddle.net/esqrg8Lc/

Comment: Non-jQuery answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1395954/74757

Comment: @Rilke for that, you should just use `"é"`. Where are you getting the entity from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9609450/2637098
and the additional information you provided, this code should suit your needs.

```js
var element = document.createElement('div');
element.innerHTML = "H&eacute;llo world!";

document.getElementById('demo1').value = element.textContent;
element.textContent = '';
```

```html
<input type="text" id="demo1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the ampersand with `&amp;`:

```js
document.write("&amp;eacute;");
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need to escape that ampersand as well? I think you should try `\&eacute;` but the idea is correct!

Comment: @MaartenBicknese There's no escaping with ```\``` in html, and you don't need to escape `&`s in JS string literals

Comment: @DarrenSweeney It works fine for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome 52.0.2743.116 - If I use jquery it works though `$('.test').html('&eacute;');`

Comment: @Bergi it certainly does make a difference on OSX + Firefox. Given answer does not work for me, yet `document.write("\&eacute;");` does.

Comment: @MaartenBicknese that sounds like FF is broken.