# decodeEntities is displaying image instead of image tag

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete, xss, htmlspecialchars

In jquery autocomplete i am using htmlspecialchars() at the json encoding for title string.When i remove that htmlspecialchars there is an XSS vulnerability.But htmlspecialchars is not escaping the "&" and '(Single Quote) in the title string.For that i've added decodeHTMLEntities by referring the following url.Now there is no XSS vulnerability and there is no escaped data aslo.But when i am giving image tag as input, it directly displaying image,instead of that i need to display the image tag code.Can anyone please help me on this.Here i am sending you my code

[How to decode HTML entities using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147359/how-to-decode-html-entities-using-jquery)

```
<?php 
  $test = htmlspecialchars( '<img src="https://google.com" ></img>',ENT_HTML401,'utf-8');
 ?>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="asd"></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var decodeEntities = (function() {
// this prevents any overhead from creating the object each time
var element = document.createElement('textarea');

function decodeHTMLEntities (str) {
if(str && typeof str === 'string') {
  // strip script/html tags
  str = str.replace(/<img[^>]*>([\S\s]*?)<\/img>/gmi, '');
  str = str.replace(/<script[^>]*>([\S\s]*?)<\/script>/gmi, '');
  str = str.replace(/<\/?\w(?:[^"'>]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*>/gmi, '');
  element.innerHTML = str;
  str = element.textContent;
  element.textContent = '';
}

 return str;
}

return decodeHTMLEntities;
})();
document.getElementById('asd').innerHTML = decodeEntities('<?php echo $asd;
?>');
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```