# extract HTML containing text nodes without encoding them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, encode

I have the following HTML:

```js
var html = jQuery('#parent').html();
console.log(html)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
  5 > 3
</div>
```

I do `jQuery('#parent').html();` and I get the following string:

```
'<div id="child"></div>
 5 &gt; 3'
```

I want to get the following string instead:

```
'<div id="child"></div>
 5 > 3'
```

How do I achieve that?

Please note that I won't know the value of the text node in advance. I simply don't want the value of the text node (if one exists) to be encoded into some html entity name.

**This question is not a duplicate** of [How to decode HTML entities using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147359/how-to-decode-html-entities-using-jquery) because **the aforementioned post does *not* answer this question**.

The current question is not about how to decode an html entity name like `&gt;` into `>`. This is easy.

The current question is about extracting HTML that *might* contain text nodes that *might* contain encodable values and I don't want any of these values to be formatted/encoded in any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, by forcing jQuery to decode the html on a element that will not be appended to the DOM.

```js
var html = jQuery('<textarea/>').html(jQuery('#parent').html()).text();

console.log(html)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
  5 > 3
</div>
```

Comment: interesting approach

Comment: oh this is beautiful - Thank you @claudio :-D

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a plain JS approach, then iterate the `childnode`s of `parent` and concatenate their values

**Demo**

```js
var html = "";
[].slice.call(document.getElementById("parent").childNodes).forEach(function(item) {
  html += (item.nodeType == 3 ? item.nodeValue : item.outerHTML);
});
console.log(html);
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
  5 > 3
</div>
```

Comment: it's too verbose compared to the other answer, on the other hand it doesn't rely on jQuery, so my apologies, it's worth an upvote for that :)