# How do we add decimal values of characters to attributes using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add the Degree Celsius `&#8457;` value to an attribute using jQuery.

```js
$("#degree-toggle").attr("value", &#8457;);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="degree-toggle" checked="checked">
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147359/how-to-decode-html-entities-using-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $("#degree-toggle").attr("value", $("<div />").html('&amp;').text());
```

Working pen:
https://codepen.io/todorutandrei/pen/OzGgmM

Answer (score 0):

You need to decode the HTML entity first. It doesn't work in attributes:

```js
$("#degree-toggle").attr("value", decodeHtml("&#8457;"));

function decodeHtml(html) {
    var txt = document.createElement("textarea");
    txt.innerHTML = html;
    return txt.value;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="degree-toggle"  checked="checked">
```

The `decodeHtml()` function works by creating a hidden textarea. Then the data which needs to be decoded is injected into that textarea and once that happened it gets read out by grabbing the "rendered" value of it.

Comment: Hi @NullDev. Thank you for your quick response. Can you please breakDown the decodeHTML function? I am not able to understand it.
your answer worked

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple and raw implementation and starts from here:

```js
$("#degree-toggle").keyup(function(){
  var newval = this.value.replace('°F',''); 
     this.value = newval + '°F';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='degree-toggle' />
```

Answer (score -1):

There's several issues here. Firstly, you're missing quotes around the value you're setting. Secondly you're using `attr('value')` instead of `val()`.

However the bigger issue is that `val()` will not decode the entity you're setting. In order to achieve that you will need to use a `<button>` element then set its `html()`, like this:

```js
$("#degree-toggle").html('&#8457;');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="degree-toggle"></button>
```

Also note that neither `<button>` nor `<input type="button">` elements have a `checked` attribute.

Comment: Looks like the downvote fairy has visited this question