# Format String for SEO friendly

Tags: javascript, jquery, format-string

I have a string like

```
Deser&#039;t  - &amp; Fest !
```

how to format this string is seo friendly like `Desert-Fest`.

In php I use the above function

```
function cleanString($str, $separator = "-"){
    $q_separator = preg_quote($separator);

    $trans = array(
        '&.+?;'                 => '',
        '[^a-z0-9 _-]'          => '',
        '\s+'                   => $separator,
        '('.$q_separator.')+'   => $separator
    );

    $str = strip_tags($str);

    foreach ($trans as $key => $val){
        $str = preg_replace("#".$key."#i", $val, $str);
    }

    $str = strtolower($str);

    return trim($str, $separator);
}
```

How to do this in Jquery?

Thanks.

Comment: `SEO` friendly by `JQ` *!* , odd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Half of your solution is to HTML-decode the entities in the input. That can be done in JS like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1912522/519413), or jQuery like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2419664/519413).

From there you can use a regular expression to remove any characters from the resulting string that you don't want, like this:

```js
function htmlDecode(input) {
  var e = document.createElement('textarea');
  e.innerHTML = input;
  return e.childNodes.length === 0 ? "" : e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}

let input = "Deser&#039;t  - &amp; Fest !";
let output = htmlDecode(input);
output = output.replace(/[^a-z-]/gi, ''); // remove anything that isn't a-Z or -
console.log(output);
```