# Javascript find and replace a set of characters?

Tags: javascript

I have a string and I need to replace all the `&#39;` and etc to their proper value

I am using

`var replace = str.replace(new RegExp("[&#39;]", "g"), "'");`

To do so, but the problem is it seems to be replacing `'` for each character (so for example, `&#39;` becomes `'''''`

Any help?

Comment: The error is in the use of `[]`. If you remove them it should work. Or use the more compact JS notation as suggested by arnaud.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this:

```
var str = str.replace(/&#39;/g, "'");
```

`[&#39;]` is a character class. It means *any of the characters inside of the braces*.

This is why your `/[&#39;]/` regex replaces every single char of `&#39;` by the replacement string.

---

If you want to use `new RegExp` instead of a regex literal:

```
var str = str.replace(new RegExp('&#39;', 'g'), "'");
```

This has no benefit, except if you want to generate regexps at runtime.

Comment: Both of these seem to generate an error "Unterminated regular expression literal"

Answer (score 6):

Take out the brackets, which makes a character class (any characters inside it match):

```
var replace = str.replace(new RegExp("&#39;", "g"), "'");
```

or even better, use a literal:

```
var replace = str.replace(/&#39;/g, "'");
```

*Edit*: See this question on how to escape HTML: [How to unescape html in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090056/how-to-unescape-html-in-javascript)

Comment: Both of these seem to generate an error "Unterminated regular expression literal"

Comment: @Steven How you are using it?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using a bunch of regex replaces for this, I would do something like this and let the browser take care of the decoding for you:

```
    function HtmlDecode(s) {
        var el = document.createElement("div");
        el.innerHTML = s;
        return el.innerText || el.textContent;
    }
```

Comment: +1 Good idea... though you don't need to call `delete el;` (it has no effect and even throws an error in strict mode). You could just do  `return el.innerText || el.textContent;`