# How to return GeoJSON with Flask to Openlayers

Tags: python, json, flask, openlayers, geojson

I have a simple flask function that renders a template with a valid GeoJSON string:

```
@app.route('/json', methods=['POST'])
def json():    
    polygon = Polygon([[[0,1],[1,0],[0,0],[0,1]]])
    return render_template('json.html',string=polygon)
```

In my json.html file, I am attempting to render this GeoJSON with OpenLayers:

```
 function init(){
            map = new OpenLayers.Map( 'map' );
            layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS", 
                    "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0",
                    {layers: 'basic'} );
            map.addLayer(layer);
            map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat), zoom);
            var fc = {{string}};        //Here is the JSON string
            var geojson_format = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON();
            var vector_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(); 
            map.addLayer(vector_layer);
            vector_layer.addFeatures(geojson_format.read(fc));
```

But this fails and the `"` characters become `'`. I have tried string formatting as seen in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380751/javascript-find-and-replace-a-set-of-characters), but it didn't work.

EDIT:

I did forget to dump my json to an actual string, I'm using the geojson library so adding the function

```
dumps(polygon)
```

takes care of that, however I still can't parse the GeoJSON in OpenLayers, even though it is a valid string according to geojsonlint.com

This is the Javascript code to create a variable from the string sent from flask:

```
var geoJson = '{{string}}';
```

And here's what it looks like in the source page:

```
'{&#34;type&#34;: &#34;Polygon&#34;, &#34;coordinates&#34;: [[[22.739485934746977, 39.26596659794341], [22.73902517923571, 39.266115931275074], [22.738329551588276, 39.26493626464484], [22.738796023230854, 39.26477459496181], [22.739485934746977, 39.26596659794341]]]}';
```

I am still having a problem rendering the quote characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like you use `shapely` which has http://toblerity.org/shapely/shapely.geometry.html#shapely.geometry.mapping method to create `GeoJSON`-like object.

To render `json` use `tojson` filter which safe (see `safe` filter) for latest flask versions, because `jinja2` in `flask` by default escape all dangerous symbols to protect XSS.

Comment: That was part of the problem, but still not there, see my edits.

Comment: All work right, dangerous symbols escaped by default with `jinja2` to protect XSS. To insert safe markup you should mark template variable as safe with `safe` filter (see `{{ string|safe }}`), but for json better use special filter `tojson` which also safe (for latest flask versions at least) and equal to `{{ flask.json.dupms(polygon)|safe }}` (see `{{ string|tojson }}`).

Comment: This is the correct answer, mind adding it to your answer text?