# How to replace "&lt;b&gt;" with "<b>" in the whole document and without jquery

Tags: javascript, replace

The following function only replaces the first "`&lt;br /&gt;`" it finds, not the following ones. Does anyone know how to fix that problem?
I want the function to replace all the strings in the whole document.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function umtauschen()
    {
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('&lt;br /&gt;', '<br />');
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('&lt;b&gt;', '<b>');
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('&lt;/b&gt;', '</b>');
    }
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Is it *just* the `br` you're replacing, or other tags too? (And I second the *why?*)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090056/how-to-unescape-html-in-javascript

Comment: Why have you got escaped tags in there in the first place? There is something you aren't telling us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use regular expressions, and the `g` (global) flag:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML
    .replace(/&lt;br \/&gt;/g, '<br />')
    .replace(/&lt;b&gt/g, '<b>')
    .replace(/&lt;\/b&gt;/g, '</b>');
```

Another option is to use the `.split(find).join(replace)` idiom:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML
    .split('&lt;br /&gt;').join('<br />')
    .split('&lt;b&gt;').join('<b>')
    .split('&lt;/b&gt;').join('</b>');
```

Answer (score 1):

following code should solve your problem:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/&lt;/g, '<').
                                                replace(/&gt;/g, '>') ;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the document is dynamic, as in generated by a script, PHP or otherwise, it's better idea to replace the tags in the DB or while printing the data. If it's a static HTML page, it's a better idea to edit code in the original file.

Dynamically replacing the entire body after page load is going to perform slowly.